# How to hide BottomNavigationBar when scrolling - Flutter

Tags: mobile, dart, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I need to implement in Flutter the hide / show feature of the BottomNavigationBar when the user scrolls the scroll down or up.
Please, if you know how to do it or have an example of how to do it and can share it, I am grateful for the help!

[Here is the link of my question there in github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23674#issuecomment-449439953)

**An example of what I want**

[image]

Comment: Try to use ScrollController. This link can help you https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-lets-know-the-scrollcontroller-and-scrollnotification-652b2685a4ac

Comment: You can add the scroll listener to your list view, check the scroll velocity, then use animation transform to translate you bottom navigator base on the scroll

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to apply your idea!

Comment: ScrollController is the right answer - why in comments, and not in the answer field?

Comment: @AndreiVolgin do you have an example to show us?

Comment: @AndreiVolgin Yes I have... https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23674

Answer (score 0):

this code for hide scrolling hide by animation

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: WorkoutDetailsPage(Workout()),
    );
  }
}

class Exercise {
  String name;
  Exercise({@required name}) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

class Workout {
  String name = "my name";
}

class WorkoutDetailsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  Workout _workout = Workout();

  WorkoutDetailsPage(this._workout);

  @override
  _WorkoutDetailsPageState createState() => _WorkoutDetailsPageState();
}


class _WorkoutDetailsPageState extends State<WorkoutDetailsPage> {
  final List<Exercise> exercises = [
    Exercise(name: "Push Ups"),
    Exercise(name: "Bench press"),
    Exercise(name: "Pull ups"),
    Exercise(name: "Press ups"),
    Exercise(name: "Crunches"),
    Exercise(name: "Sit ups"),
    Exercise(name: "BIceps curl"),
    Exercise(name: "Something else"),
    Exercise(name: "Push Ups"),
    Exercise(name: "Bench press"),
    Exercise(name: "Pull ups"),
    Exercise(name: "Press ups"),
    Exercise(name: "Crunches"),
    Exercise(name: "Sit ups"),
    Exercise(name: "BIceps curl"),
    Exercise(name: "Something else"),
    Exercise(name: "Push Ups"),
    Exercise(name: "Bench press"),
    Exercise(name: "Pull ups"),
    Exercise(name: "Press ups"),
    Exercise(name: "Crunches"),
    Exercise(name: "Sit ups"),
    Exercise(name: "BIceps curl"),
    Exercise(name: "Something else"),
    Exercise(name: "Push Ups"),
    Exercise(name: "Bench press"),
    Exercise(name: "Pull ups"),
    Exercise(name: "Press ups"),
    Exercise(name: "Crunches"),
    Exercise(name: "Sit ups"),
    Exercise(name: "BIceps curl"),
    Exercise(name: "Something else"),
    Exercise(name: "Push Ups"),
    Exercise(name: "Bench press"),
    Exercise(name: "Pull ups"),
    Exercise(name: "Press ups"),
    Exercise(name: "Crunches"),
    Exercise(name: "Sit ups"),
    Exercise(name: "BIceps curl"),
    Exercise(name: "Something else"),
  ];

  ScrollController _hideButtonController;

  bool _isVisible = true;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _isVisible = true;
    _hideButtonController = new ScrollController();
    _hideButtonController.addListener(() {
      print("listener");
      if (_hideButtonController.position.userScrollDirection ==
          ScrollDirection.reverse) {
        setState(() {
          _isVisible = false;
          print("**** $_isVisible up");
        });
      }
      if (_hideButtonController.position.userScrollDirection ==
          ScrollDirection.forward) {
        setState(() {
          _isVisible = true;
          print("**** $_isVisible down");
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButtonAnimator: FloatingActionButtonAnimator.scaling,
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      floatingActionButton: _isVisible
          ? FloatingActionButton(
              backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
              elevation: 12,
              onPressed: () {},
            )
          : null,
      bottomNavigationBar: AnimatedContainer(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
        height: _isVisible ? 60 : 0.0,
        child: BottomAppBar(
          elevation: 8,
          shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: Container(
            height: 60,
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[Text("data")],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: CustomScrollView(
        controller: _hideButtonController,
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            expandedHeight: 150,
            pinned: true,
            floating: true,
            snap: true,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              title: Text(widget._workout.name),
            ),
          ),
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(buildSliverListItem,
                childCount: exercises.length),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildSliverListItem(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Center(
      child: ListTile(
        title: Text(exercises[index].name),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Or u https://medium.com/nonstopio/hide-or-show-app-bar-and-bottom-navigation-bar-while-scrolling-in-flutter-3994f78e52c0